# JavaFX - Looking for solution for XYChart subclasses gridlines not panning

Tags: charts, javafx, javafx-8, candlestick-chart

I am working on a financial type of charting system. I've managed to get some of the things working but I am encountering an issue when I implement the chart panning: the contents of the chart (actual data) pans with the drag action, however the vertical gridlines remain static and do not follow the data; their values are instead seemingly updated.

Similarly the x-Axis remains static as opposed to scrolling with the chart contents.

I have included a quick video demonstrating what I want the chart to do (linechart) and what it is currently doing (candlestick chart):

http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/coQ3FhfsHk

Here is the main code for both the financial chart inmplementation and the pannable line chart:
https://gist.github.com/autronix/02055fa16fd2a41dd905

So far I have been unable to figure out which part of the code is creating this behavior and identify how to correct it.

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your first example, the change in the grid lines is because of the change in the range of your Y-axis. The `autoRanging` feature in a XYChart is set to true by default and when your chart exceeds the present range, it auto-arranges the axis, grid lines and therefore the graph itself. In your second example, your `ScatterChart` never exceeds the range of your Y-axis.

Comment: I am not really concerned about the Y axis gridlines (the ones begind the chart), my issue is with the x-axis gridlines that are static, these remain at the same place (along with the x-axis values at the bottom) instead of scrolling right and left. In the first example you can see the x-axis values scrolling as I pan the graph with the mouse, the second example does not show this behavior.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem. In the video ,I can see the initial x-axis lower value as `9:29 AM` and at the end the lower value is around `2 PM`. So, when you are dragging the chart the x-axis values are changing.

Comment: That's correct, the values are changing, but the position of the x-axis tick values always remain the same. They are not scrolling (ie. using the whole space to move across the screen), instead, the values at each tick are being replaced as the candelstick chart is scrolled; you can see the right behavior in the linechart on the video (the x-axis values move as opposed to being replaced in their position)